# Android: ListView Not Working In OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to create a `ListView` that contains a `CheckBox` for To-List App.

I've already coded the `CheckBox` correctly so I am trying to display the `CheckBox` inside the `ListView`.

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/taskListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_task"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="New Task"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Create" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.taskListView);

                EditText newTask = findViewById(R.id.new_task);

                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(MainActivity.this);

                String task = newTask.getText().toString();
                newTask.setText(task);
                checkBox.setText(task);

                ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, task);
                ListView taskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskListView);
                taskListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've written the Java code for `ListView` but get this error:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, int, java.lang.String)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are passing clicklistner to adapter but your adapter wants context

first of all create context object and pass your activitiy to that context

in your AppCompatActivity activity add:

```
private Context context ;
```

then initialise this context in onCreate like :

```
context = this ;
```

secondly you will need to pass list to your adapter.so create string arraylist of your tasks and pass to your adapter

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>() ;
list.add(task) ;
```

and now pass this context & list to arrayadapter :

```
myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a custom ListView-Adapter displaying the checkbox and the text in one layout. If you only want to display the texts without a checkbox, you can use something like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<String> tasks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tasks=new ArrayList<String>();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.taskListView);

            EditText newTask = findViewById(R.id.new_task);

            String task = newTask.getText().toString();
            tasks.add(task);

            ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tasks.toArray(new String[0]));
            ListView taskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskListView);
            taskListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
        }
    });
}
}
```

With a checkbox, it get's a lot more complicated: You have to define a custom layout and a custom array adapter.

The array adapter looks like this:

```java
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {  

    private final Activity context;  
    private final String[] tasks;  
    private final boolean[] completed; 

    public MyListAdapter(Activity context, String[] tasks,boolean[] completed) {  
        super(context, R.layout.mylist, maintitle);  
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  

        this.context=context;  
        this.tasks=tasks;  
        this.completed=completed; 
    }  

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {  
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();  
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);  

        Checkbox check = (Checkbox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        TextView task = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.task);  

        check.setChecked(completed[position]);
        task.setText(tasks[position]); 

        return rowView;  

    }  
}
```

The custom layout as `mylist.xml` is the following:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Checkbox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrapContent"
        android:layout_height="wrapContent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Task"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you have to change the main class to:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<String> tasks;
List<boolean> completed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tasks=new ArrayList<String>();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.taskListView);

            EditText newTask = findViewById(R.id.new_task);

            String task = newTask.getText().toString();
            tasks.add(task);
            completed.add(false);

            MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, tasks.toArray(new String[0]), completed.toString(new boolean[0]));
            ListView taskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskListView);
            taskListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
        }
    });
}
}
```

EDIT:
If you only want to use Java-Code to create the entries, you can replace the getView Method in the custom adapter with the following:

```java
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout rowView=new LinearLayout(context);  

        Checkbox check = new Checkbox(context);
        TextView task = new TextView(context);  

        check.setChecked(completed[position]);
        task.setText(tasks[position]); 

        rowView.addView(check);
        rowView.addView(task);

        return rowView;  

    }
```

Then you can delete the `mylist.xml` file.

Comment: The Java Code is supposed to create the CheckBox. You've created a CheckBox in the XML.

Comment: The XML-Code is a blueprint for all ListView-Entries. So for every entry, you have every View declared in the file.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I've also edited my answer with how you can avoid the .xml file.